# Is the definition of shared_ptr constructor wrong in cppreferece?

Tags: c++, c++14

On p.127 of Scott Meyers' book Effective C++14 item 19, he says that deleter type of a shared_ptr is not a template parameter but in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr, the (4) constructor has Deleter as one of the template parameter.

I tried it myself in g++10.2. Something like below won't compile:

```
auto deleter = [](foo* p) {
        std::cout << "delete ***" << std::endl;
        delete p;
};
std::shared_ptr<foo, decltype(deleter)> sp1(new foo, deleter); // error
```

So I suppose cppreference is wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: When was Effective C++ written, and does it have any published errata? The standard has probably changed since the book was written.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing something.

The template arguments you are seeing on cppreference are the template parameters to the constructor function template, not to the `shared_ptr` class.

There are actually a total of three template arguments in play here:

```
namespace std {
    ...
    template<typename T>
    class shared_ptr
    {
        ...
        template<typename Y, typename Deleter>
        shared_ptr( Y*, Deleter );
        ...
    };
    ...
}

template<typename T>
template<typename Y, typename Deleter>
std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr( Y*, Deleter ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. May I ask in what situation you need/want to have T and Y different?

Comment: @Gary: Polymorphism.  Maybe you have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>` and want to emplace allocated objects of type `Derived1` and `Derived2`.  You could create a `std::shared_ptr<Derived1>` and convert it to `std::shared_ptr<Base>` but you can also create a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` directly from a `Derived1*`.

Comment: @Remy can you explain why you made that edit?  It doesn't look like an improvement to me.

Comment: @BenVoigt it makes it clearer that the first template is on the class itself, and the second template is on the constructor. Most everyone familiar with using templates will recognize the use of inline definitions, but not everyone will be used to seeing use of a definition separated from its declaration, especially one with two templates attached to it.

Comment: @Remy: But in fact both templates (and all three arguments) are on the constructor.  Inline notation hides that fact.